# C#/WPF: Closing the current window without closing the whole project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project which acts as a boardgame. In this board game, I have multiple mini-games that the user can play (memory game, tic-tac-toe,  minesweeper.) My problem is how to not close down the whole project when asking the user if he wants to start a new game so that he can play the other games.

I have the board game window as the base window, inside that window I have the grids for the games.

For example, when I win the tic-tac-toe a message box pops up asking if I want to start a new game with options yes and no. However, If I choose no, it will close the whole project instead of just stopping to play the tic-tac-toe.

in the tic-tac-toe.cs I have this method for closing the tic-tac-toe game:

```
  internal void newGame(string message)
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show("Play Again?", message, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                Clear(); // calls the method to clear buttons etc.
            }
            else
            {
                //Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
                //Application.Current.Windows[Application.Current.Windows.Count - 1].Close();

            }
        }
```

As you can see both lines in Else are commented as they do close down the whole project instead of just the tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: What happens if you just have `Application.Current.Windows[Application.Current.Windows.Count - 1].Close();` in your else statement ?

Comment: So basically you have just **one** window in your application? If so, you cannot close that window, just hide your tic-tac-toe grid by setting it's visiblity to collapsed.

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()` will always close the current window, which, in your case is the container for other small games. I presume that small game is not a new Window derived from `Application`. As you have stated that you are using grid, then I would suggest you to restore it to initial state.

Comment: You should create `UserControl`s for the games, just create/destroy them when a game is selected. This way you keep the game logic separated from each other. I could make an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the main window's window closing event:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //You can ask users to play new games, if they click close window (etc.)
    e.Cancel = true; //This will cancel the closing of main window.
    //You can now write logic to close your local windows (dispose objects of games) and show the main window.
}
```